# How to understand Inline boxes may also be split into several boxes within the same line box

Tags: css

There is a description about “[Inline formatting contexts](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/visuren.html#inline-formatting:%7E:text=inline%20boxes%20may%20also%20be%20split%20into%20several%20boxes%20within%20the%20same%20line%20box%20due%20to%20bidirectional%20text%20processing.)” in CSS 2.2 specification:

> Inline boxes may also be split into several boxes within the same line box due to [bidirectional text processing](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/visuren.html#direction).

I don't understand what this means literally, so I checked the example on bidirectional text processing from the given link, but still, I don't quite understand the exact meaning. Here is how I understand this example:

1. The "HEBREW18 english19 HEBREW20" from below is the inline block to split.

```
english17 20WERBEH english19 18WERBEH
```

2. This inline block is split into two boxes: "18WERBEH" and "20WERBEH english19", according to the display below:

```
english17 18WERBEH
20WERBEH english19
```

But what does "within the same line box" mean? Here "the same line box" means the first line of "english17 18WERBEH", or the second line of "20WERBEH english19"?

Kindly let me know if my understanding is right, and if wrong what does this exactly supposed to mean?

Comment: I honestly wouldn't place too much store on what CSS 2.2 says. CSS 3 tends to describe these things differently and more accurately. "The same line box" would mean _any_ and _every_ line box in which contained bidirection text. Whether, however, bidirectional text alone actually causes multiple inline boxes in the CSS 3 sense to be created is I think doubtful.

Comment: @Alohci Thanks for your reply. Today I accidentally noticed following paragraph: "Please note that in order to be able to flow inline boxes in a uniform direction (either entirely left-to-right or entirely right-to-left), more inline boxes (including anonymous inline boxes) may have to be created, and some inline boxes may have to be split up and reordered before flowing." in 9.10. Text direction section from CSS 2.2 specification. I think may be this is what "Inline boxes may also be split into several boxes within the same line box due to bidirectional text processing." means.

Comment: From my understanding, inline boxes is here split up generally for the purpose of reordering (flow in a uniform direction), and it happens before flowing.

Comment: Yes that's what CSS 2.2 says. And that understanding is _probably_ good enough. My caution to you is simply that I don't think that's what CSS 3 says, so if you need a detailed understanding of the relationship of bidirectional text and inline boxes, you should go read the [CSS 3 Writing mode spec](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-writing-modes/#text-direction),